# Submitting Plugin Update Through SVN to Wordpress Doesn't Reflect Changes

Tags: svn, plugins, wordpress

I released 2 days ago an update to my Wordpress plugin. Which can be viewed here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lanoba-social/

The version went from 1.3 to 2.0 and (now to 2.01 as a test). When I look at the subversion repository, all my changes are reflected on Wordpress' servers. http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/lanoba-social/trunk/

In fact, all websites using our plugin are detecting that there are updates too (and updates are succesful).

The problem is that the description of the plugin, the changelog and installation instructions (see first link) are not reflecting the visible changes in svn (see 2nd link).

The weird thing is that the screenshots ARE displaying the new ones and I am able to rename the plugin but it stops there.

If anyone has any ideas on what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of steps involved in checking in a new version and I find it a little fiddly myself.  You have to do the following:

- update the "stable" version number in the readme.txt file
- make a new tagged release in SVN with that version number
- update the version number in the plugin's main .php file, which I think is the version number that displays

You have to get all three in sync for it to work, and there are no error indications if you have one wrong, unfortunately.

If you only update the version number in the main .php file, I think you can see the new version number displayed but the repository's idea of who is current doesn't get updated.  This is kind of a trap, and I had difficulties with it myself.

I know this is an old question by now and you have probably answered it yourself, but thought it was worth adding an answer as people may be searching for it.

FAQ defining where the various fields come from:
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/faq/

How to manage a plugin using SVN:
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/svn/

Note: this 'manage a plugin using SVN' document describes how to update a release and explicitly mentions updating the Stable Tag in the trunk/readme.txt file.  **I strongly suspect that the version displayed on the plugin page is taken from the plugin main .php file, while the actual version from which the update is made is taken from readme.txt stable tag and the svn tagged release.**  In my mind this is probably a bug, highly confusing at least, and I think definitely undocumented ...